# Is it possible to use js in magento block?

Tags: javascript, magento, static, block

I have used `{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/FILE_NAME.phtml"}}` in my static block and want to  use in the home page. 
Before that I have used the block in my home page and in the 'design' part of the home page I have written

```
<reference name="block_name">
<action method="addJs">
<script>js_name</script>
</action>
</reference>
```

But it's not working . Can anyone help me out?....

Comment: if you want to use js before the block, whyn't you write in you `FILE_NAME.phtml` on top

Answer (score 0):

if you are using that particular block only in homepage you can add using `head` reference under homepage `layout handle`. Here is how it is..

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>js_name</script></action>
   </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: I have used this in my local.xml and also in homepage layout update xml portion.... but the block I want to use the js on..still not showing its work... is it the right way ? or u want me to do else?...

Comment: rather than on block specific, we do load on particular layout handles's head section. This would also ensure us to have that being loaded before other contents. And in my case if this block is being used on homepage i would load like above or in the case i have vary less portion of script i do write on same phtml file of block(for eg. some carousel activating specific).

Comment: The js I want to use on some elements that is okay if I use in .phtml files but for using static block its not working....

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your home page design section

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_js" as="custom_js" template="custom/js.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

and in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/custom/js.phtml` add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //your js here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue just taking the pictures from the static block(which will be given by the admin) and other things like js and divs I have defined in the .phtml page .....and its works.